# Eclipse起動時にMissing 'tools.jar'というエラーが表示される

Tags: java, eclipse, java8

Eclipseを起動するしたときに以下のエラーが出るのですが、

[image: 起動時に出るエラー]

設定のインストール済JRE にtool.jarのパスを追加しても同様で、なぜこのようなエラーがでるのでしょうか？環境変数やインストールに問題があるのでしょうか？

[image: 設定]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipseを起動するために、JREを使用しているからですかね。

`tools.jar`はJREではなく、JDKに含まれています。ただ単にEclipseを起動するだけなら、JREで十分ですが、エラーダイアログにあるSpring Boot Live hoversがJDKを必要としているので、このメッセージが出るのだと思います。

Eclipseを動かしているJava VMを確認する方法は、[このページ](https://itsakura.com/eclipse-javavm)に書いてあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通り、JREで起動されていました。
Eclipse起動に使うjavaw.exeを指定したところ、java vmがjdkを指定するようになり、起動時のエラーも消えました。


javaw.exeの指定は以下の[サイト](https://qiita.com/gate9/items/cef12860351bfce762e6)を参考にしました